# Is it possible to modify/rebuild an rpm without the srpm?

Tags: package-management, rpm, rpmbuild

I have an rpm for which I need to change the preinstal scriptlet for testing.

However, I do not have the SRPM from which is was built.

Is it possible to change the scriptlet and/or rebuild the rpm *without* having the SRPM?

If so, how?

I've tried using Midnight Commander (`mc`) to open the rpm as a directory structure and edit the contents, but even with `666` permissions, it won't let me save any changes.

Comment: 444 permissions are just "everybody can read"; no write permissions there.  you need 7 for read-write-execute -- 700 for you, 777 for everybody.

Comment: @quack quixote - I meant '666', fixing now

Comment: yeah, 444 does look a lot ... less evil, doesn't it?  :)

Comment: @quack quixote - it does indeed :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What is needed is [rpmrebuild](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net), which I found via the Red Hat Magazine [article](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/12/04/hacking-rpms-with-rpmrebuild).

If you have an rpm for which you only wish to modify the spec file, do the following:

1. copy the rpm in question to a working directory
2. run `rpmrebuild -e -p <pkg>rpm`   <sub><sup>(this will open your default editor (typically `vi|vim` if you haven't made any changes on your rpm-based distro), allowing you to make changes to the spec file)</sup></sub>
3. find the line(s) you wish to change
4. make changes
5. save and exit your editor   <sub><sup>(<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> in `vi[m]`, Ctrl-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> in `emacs`)</sup></sub>
6. `rpmrebuild` will ask if you want to continue
7. answer 'yes'
8. the rebuilt package will show up in `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/<arch>/<pkg>.rpm`

Comment: and the downvote is for ...?

Comment: doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: thx for the solution, it helped me fix my rpm removing %files problematic lines